# createdb error: while create and sync database in django (windows7)

Tags: django, postgresql

Im following the  tutorial 
https://code.google.com/p/geodjango-basic-apps/wiki/FOSS4GWorkshop

When I create sync database Im getting the error

```
    createdb error: could not connect to database template1: could not connect to server:Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting 
TCP/IP connections on port 5432? received invalid response to SSL negotiation: -
```

My postgres is running on port 5433 and I have made the necessary changes in postgresql.conf. I have set

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port=5433
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer you are look for.
I've always had various problems with postgre on a windows machine, which is why I switch to ubuntu after all. 
But when I wanted used it with windows I ended up using [Vagrant](http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/getting-started/index.html) which worked out pretty well and was very easy to install (if you are using pycharm, you even have a wizard for settings it up with vagrant; the debugger works flawless with it as well).
This is what my `provisioning.sh` looked like. Just put it in the root of your project, install vagrant and call `vagrant up`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "----- CONFIGURE SYSTEM -----"
echo "--- Disable IPv6 (Step 1/1)"
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
echo "net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1" >/etc/sysctl.d/01-disable-ipv6.conf

echo on
echo "--- SYSTEM REQUIREMENTS -----"
echo "--- APT-GET UPDATE (SYSREQ Step 1/5)"
apt-get update
echo "--- INSTALL PYTHON-PIP (SYSREQ Step 2/5)"
apt-get install -y python-pip
echo "--- INSTALL PYTHON-DEV (SYSREQ Step 3/5)"
apt-get install -y python-dev
echo "--- INSTALL LIBPQ-DEV (SYSREQ Step 4/5)"
apt-get install -y libpq-dev
echo "--- INSTALL LIBMYSQLCLIENT-DEV (SYSREQ Step 5/5)"
apt-get install -y libmysqlclient-dev

echo ----- POSTGRES -----
echo "--- INSTALL POSTGRES (POSTGRES Step 1/6)"
apt-get install -y postgresql
echo "--- INSTALL POSTGRES-CLIENT (POSTGRES Step 2/6)"
apt-get install -y postgresql-client
echo "--- START POSTGRES (POSTGRES Step 3/6)"
postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data >logfile 2>&1 &
echo "--- CREATE DB (POSTGRES Step 4/6)"
su -c "createdb --encoding='utf-8' --locale=en_US.utf8 --template=template0 project_name_db" postgres
echo "--- LOAD DB IMAGE (POSTGRES Step 5/6)"
su -c "psql project_name_db < /vagrant/vagrant-database/project_namedb.sql" postgres
echo "--- CREATE VAGRANT POSTGRES USERS (POSTGRES Step 6/6)"
su -c "createuser -s vagrant" postgres
su -c "createuser -s root" postgres

echo ----- GIT -----
apt-get install -y git

echo ----- RUBY -----
echo "--- INSTALL SASS (RUBY Step 1/4)"
gem install sass -v 3.2.9
echo "--- INSTALL CHUNKY_PNG (RUBY Step 2/4)"
gem install chunky_png -v 1.2.8
echo "--- INSTALL FSSM (RUBY Step 3/4)"
gem install fssm -v 0.2.10
echo "--- INSTALL COMPASS (RUBY Step 4/4)"
gem install compass -v 0.12.2

echo ----- PYTHON -----
echo "--- INSTALL REQUIREMENTS (PYTHON Step 1/1)"
pip install -r /vagrant/requirements_local.txt

echo ----- LOCALE -----
echo "--- INSTALL GERMAN LANGUAGE PACK"
apt-get install language-pack-de

echo ----- PREPARING SERVER -----
echo "--- MIGRATE (RUN SERVER Step 2/2)"
python /vagrant/manage.py migrate --settings=project_name.settomgs.settings_local_dev_vagrant

echo "Server is ready to go! Execute the following command inside the VM to run the server:"
echo "python /vagrant/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080 --settings=project_name.settings.settings_local_dev_vagrant"
echo ----- PROVISIONING FINISHED  -----
```

Hope that helps!